# Selecting rows in a given range from grouped object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks similar to this one:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------+
|    action  |  ts                 |   uid   |
+------------+---------------------+---------+
| action1    | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | 543534  |  
| action2    | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | 543544  |
| action1    | 2013-01-01 00:00:02 | 543542  |
| action2    | 2013-01-01 00:00:03 | 543541  |
|   ....     |       ....          |   ...   |
+------------+---------------------+---------+
```

I want to count number of `actions` of every type performed by each user in a given timerange, so the expected output is smth like this:

```
    uid action1 action2
543534    10      1
543534    0      2
 ...
```

I was thinking to solve the problem by first applying `.groupby('uid')` then iterating through the grouped object, selecting rows then `ts` is in a given range, then concatenating dataframes into resulting dataframe, sorting

So, smth like that:

```
df = ...
start_date = ...
end_date = ...
result = {}

grouped = df.groupby('uid')
grouped_dict = dict(list(grouped))

for item in grouped.keys:
    df = grouped[item]    
    result[item] = df[df.ts > start_date and df.ts < end_date].size()
```

I haven't run this code, but I think even if it works it's extremely inefficient. Even converting grouped object to the dictionary takes a lot of time. What would be more efficient approach in this case?

Comment: Have you noticed that you can actually group by more than one key?

Comment: If you can enumerate the time ranges, then you can groupby those two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group both by `uid` and `action`:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2013-01-01 00:00:00')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2013-01-01 00:00:07')
print df
print df[(df.ts > start_date) & (df.ts < end_date)].groupby(['uid','action'])['ts'].count().unstack('action').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
    action                  ts  uid
0  action1 2013-01-01 00:00:00    1
1  action2 2013-01-01 00:00:00    2
2  action1 2013-01-01 00:00:02    2
3  action2 2013-01-01 00:00:03    1
4  action2 2013-01-01 00:00:04    2
5  action2 2013-01-01 00:00:05    1
6  action1 2013-01-01 00:00:06    1
action  action1  action2
uid                     
1             1        2
2             1        1
```

Comment: If you have 0.13 you can make this slightly more readable by doing `df.query('@start_date < ts < @end_date')`

Comment: Oh, that was obvious! Shame on me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the interface of `pandas.DataFrame`, I'd select the data like this:

```
# Select the interesting date range
bydate = df[(df['ts'] > start_date & df.ts < end_date]
# Now this will group for uid, *then* by action
grouped = bydate.groupby(('uid', 'action'))
```

Now, let's just print the number of actions per uid:

```
for indices, data in grouped:
    print("Uid {}, Action '{}': {}".format(indices[0], indices[1], len(data))
```

Comment: `and` is not valid syntax for numpy arrays